# Delphi XE7 Android Indy IRC

Tags: android, delphi, indy

After join channel application will terminate self after few seconds. Program is run on real telephone LG L65 (no signed), i have one event IdIRC1Raw. Any suggestion?

```
procedure THeaderFooterwithNavigation.IdIRC1Raw(ASender: TIdContext; AIn: Boolean; const AMessage: string);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(AMessage)
end;
```

Comment: My suggestion is to stop using delphi on android platform ... any logs in logcat? Maybe indy component using wrong threads

Comment: i run this apk on real phone, no loggin

Comment: Does it work correctly in the emulator?

Comment: i dont use emulator (too slow computer)

Comment: The official Android emulator is slow in general.  Use another emulator, like BlueStacks or Genymotion. They are much faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `AIn` parameter is true, the `OnRaw` event handler is being called in the context of a worker thread running inside of `TIdIRC` (represented by the `AContext` parameter).  When `AIn` is false, `OnRaw` is being called in the context of whatever thread you are sending a command in (and `AContext` is nil).

Because `OnRaw` is not always run in the context of the main UI thread, you must synchronize with the main UI thread in order to update the Memo safely, eg:

```
procedure THeaderFooterwithNavigation.IdIRC1Raw(ASender: TIdContext; AIn: Boolean; const AMessage: string);
begin
  TThread.Synchronize(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add(AMessage);
    end
  );
end;
```

However, keep in mind that prior to XE7, [`TThread.Synchronize()` was broken in FireMonkey](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=123579), though there is a simple workaround available (mentioned in the above link):

```
procedure THeaderFooterwithNavigation.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CheckSynchronize;
end;
```